# Illegal characters in path in console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application

I am going to access a text file from console application and having some data like this-

```
Auto 2017
Mech 2056
CSE 2016
```

Error occurred when read file, please see the attached screen.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Please edit your question so that both the code and error message are present as *text* rather than as a screenshot.

Comment: put code instead of image, it will help more

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to take the *text* of the file, and then load it as if that were another filename. In other words, you're asking to read a file called "Auto 2017 Mech 2056 CSE 2016" including line breaks. That file doesn't exist, does it?

Get rid of your first `File.ReadAllText` call, and instead use

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\Users\admin\...as before...");
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already read all text from your file and stored it in `text` variable. your `text` should contain `file path` like this:

```
string text = @"c:\about\ full-path";
```

Answer (score 0):

[`System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) expects a valid path as input, you are giving a text instead. that causes the error, give a valid path to get it worked;

```
string filePath=@"C:\sample.txt"; //  or something like this
string[] lines=System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove this line**

```
string[] lines= System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(text);
```

**Replace with below line and try it**

```
string[] lines = text.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```